# Spring Boot Creating Own Starter

Tags: maven, spring-boot, import

I'm following a chapter "Extending Spring Boot Apps" from the book "Pro Spring Boot". In this chapter the writer starts by explaining how to create your own spring-boot-starter-. Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-boot/tree/master/ch14/journal). I'm quite new to both maven and spring.

It works fine if I use the same spring-boot version as the writer, 1.3.3.RELEASE. But it does not work with the current version of spring-boot, and I want to make it work with the current version.

The basic folder structure:

```
**/journal/
|-- spring-boot-journal
|   |-- src
|   |-- pom.xml
|-- journal-spring-boot-autoconfigure
|   |-- src
|   |-- pom.xml
|-- journal-spring-boot-starter
|   |-- src
|   |-- pom.xml
|-- pom.xml
```

The error I get, after executing '**/journal/mvn clean package -DskipTests=true', when using the spring-boot version 1.4.2.RELEASE instead of 1.3.3.RELEASE is:

> **/journal-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/**/JournalAutoConfiguration.java cannot find symbol: class JournalRepository

Importing classes from the submodule spring-boot-journal does not work anymore. [The spring-boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) does not cover how to import from a submodule in the -spring-boot-autoconfigure module. How would I do/fix this in the current version of spring-boot (1.4.2.RELEASE)?

I noticed a difference between the jar packaging which could explain the error:

> 1.4.2.RELEASE: BOOT-INF/classes/com/apress/spring/repository/JournalRepository.class
>
> 1.3.3.RELEASE: com/apress/spring/repository/JournalRepository.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module in which `JournalRepository` must remain a module and not a full-blown Spring Boot application. Looking at the source code it's clearly not the case so I am going to reach out to Felipe to see if that can be changed.

In 1.4 (as you've discovered yourself), the packaging has changed to enforce this: rather than putting classes at the usual location for a "simple jar" we now put them in a separate location to make things consistent (you wouldn't use a war as a library dependency either).

The updated documentation of the maven plugin explains [how you can use a `classifier` so that the main artifact remains a simple library](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html)